# Unable to understand the execution when using the logical operators

Tags: c++, c, logical-operators

This is the code :

```
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a=-3 , b=2 , c=0, d;
    d = ++a && ++b || ++c;
    printf("a=%d , b=%d , c=%d, d=%d ",a,b,c,d);
    getch();
}
```

Output : `-2 , 3 , 0 , 1`

I am unable to understand that why value of `c` is not incremented, I think it should be `1` and how come output of `d = 1`.

Comment: Please note that the answer is *totally* different than if you had asked about the very similar-seeming expression `d = ++a & ++b | ++c;` .

Answer (score 7):

The statement;

```
d = ++a && ++b || ++c;
```

Is grouped left to right (given the [precedence of `&&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence));

```
d = (++a && ++b) || ++c;
```

Hence, when evaluating the `&&`, since the first operand is true (the `++a`), the second is evaluated (the `++b`). At this point, the result of this logical AND is `true`; hence the logical OR is true and its second operand is not evaluated (the `++c`).

This behaviour is guaranteed and is commonly known as short circuit evaluation. The wording for this in the standards for C++ and C is [listed here, in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912619/3747990); briefly reproduced here for C++;

*§5.14 Logical AND operator*

> 1 The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). The result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.

*§5.15 Logical OR operator*

> 1 The `||` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It returns true if either of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike `|`, `||` guarantees left-to-right evaluation; moreover, the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true.